# java errors that don't occur on Windows, but do in Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, cxf, embedded-jetty

My company is moving to a target architecture that uses Ubuntu; we are migrating java applications from Windows.  Our first application is running into this error on Ubuntu (runs fine on Win):

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: > org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/lifecycle/ResourceProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.lifecycle.ResourceProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

Both environments are running java 1.8 jdk/jre (NOT OpenJDK on Ubuntu). We use an internal CodeCloud for git and everything is updated in both Win and Ubuntu.  Maven shows all the dependencies have been met; I can even expand the maven classes and can see the ResourceProvider class.

I have read about versioning problems with Spring and CXF, but that refers to a version of CXF older than we are running, and I don't see anything that indicates why the code would run in the Windows environment, but not the 'nix environment.  Also a lot of talk about WebLogic, where we are using embedded Jetty with CXF for the server side.  This is a standalone console application that is not using a container, if that even matters.

Any thoughts or tips would be appreciated.

Edit: This error is occurring using 'run as java' in eclipse.  Debugger doesn't even hit the first line of code in main.

[image]

Comment: One also should not forget all those tiny differences; path :/; , backslash/slash, **case-sensitive**, rights.

Comment: @joop You're correct.  I've double checked file system paths in both code and resource files.

Comment: Please edit your question and add how is your product packaged and started? (set of jars? traditional classpath? uber-jar? straight command line? scripts to start it? wrapper libs to start it? etc) - past answers for this specific question have been uber-jar packaging mistakes.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt edited as requested.  This is occurring from within eclipse using 'run as java'

Comment: @EricO your classpath in your "run as java" in eclipse is bad/wrong, but without more details we cannot point to what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt It's a Maven project, and I can see the correct dependency in the list of Maven Dependencies.  I added a screenshot to illustrate.  I'm not sure what other information I could provide to help.

Comment: It's unlikely to be your Maven setup/situation, it's your "Run as Java" configuration, something is off with your Run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I started over with this machine and was able to get it running.  I believe I either had a bad "how-to" for installing the Oracle JDK on linux, or I left out the commands

update-alternatives - install ... javac

update-alternatives - install ... javaws

I should have paid more attention when going through these steps so I could give a better solution, but really, I just don't recall entering those commands the first time around.